# How to add missing dependencies in android 9?

Tags: opengl-es, android-source, android-9.0-pie

we are working in android pie BSP, while building the file we are getting some missing dependencies error but we added the missing libraries in vendor/lib folder that is externally compiled file. is there any way to access the library or can anyone tell where to place the library to access?

The error is

```
frameworks/base/cmds/simpletriangle_vivante-fb/Android.mk: error: simpletriangle_vivante-fb (EXECUTABLES android-arm) missing libEGL-fb (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm) 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
frameworks/base/cmds/simpletriangle_vivante-fb/Android.mk: error: simpletriangle_vivante-fb (EXECUTABLES android-arm) missing libGAL-fb (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm) 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
frameworks/base/cmds/simpletriangle_vivante-fb/Android.mk: error: simpletriangle_vivante-fb (EXECUTABLES android-arm) missing libGLESv2-fb (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm) 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Make Sure that you have the latest hardware files.

You can `ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true` in Your `BoardConfig.mk`

Comment: This is not an actual solution and only causes problem at the end.